# wordpress upgrade from 4.2.1 to 4.7.3 500 error

Tags: plugins, upgrade, 500-internal-error

For some reason, WordPress wont let me automatically upgrade, so i am going down the manual root.

I have uploaded the contents of wp-admin and wp-includes, backing up the previous folders.

When trying to navigate to the frontend, or even admin i just get a 500 error.

I have disabled all plugins, and even reverted to the default twentyfifteen theme by updating the database options "stylesheet" and "template".

Doing this still produces the 500 error. If i revert the files back to before the upgrade, everything works fine.

Any ideas what the issue could be?

Comment: You can check the errors.log to find out more about cause of error 500. It is in general that you might have some directories permission issue or some php parsing error.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to track down the cause of a 500 error, so here's what I'd try:

1. Be sure to also copy the new root folder files (except `wp-config.php`) - not just the `wp-admin` and `wp-includes` directories.
2. Go the other way around. Make a backup copy of the current `wp-content` directory and your `wp-config.php` file. Do a complete fresh install of the WordPress files from the latest zip and then copy the `wp-config.php` to the install root and copy the `wp-content` folder over the new one.